# Confusion about different running times of two algorithms in C

Tags: c

I have an array, `long matrix[8*1024][8*1024]`, and two functions `sum1` and `sum2`:

```
long sum1(long m[ROWS][COLS]) {
    long register sum = 0;
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < COLS; j++) {
            sum += m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

long sum2(long m[ROWS][COLS]) {
    long register sum = 0;
    int i,j;

    for (j=0; j < COLS; j++) {
        for (i=0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            sum += m[i][j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

When I execute the two functions with the given array, I get running times:

sum1: 0.19s

sum2: 1.25s

Can anyone explain why there is this huge difference?

Comment: You compiled with all retail optimizations on, right?

Comment: @selbie I used gcc -0O -lrt matrix_sum.c -o matrix_sum

Comment: As an aside, the `register` keyword doesn't do much of anything these days.  Compilers pretty much ignore it aside from the fact that a `register`-qualified variable is not addressable.

Comment: If your timing program executes the same function over and over again, then you are timing how efficiently the hardware moves the matrix into your cache. If your cache is large enough, the whole matrix will fit into the cache after the first pass, and the timing differences will be minimal.

Comment: I wonder if loop interchange optimization would render the two implementations equally fast, as seen in [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/3258851).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Computers generally use *cache* to help speed up access to main memory.

The hardware usually used for main memory is relatively slow—it can take many processor cycles for data to come from main memory to the processor. So a computer generally includes a smaller amount very fast but expensive memory called cache. Computers may have several levels of cache, some of it is built into the processor or the processor chip itself and some of it is located outside the processor chip.

Since the cache is smaller, it cannot hold everything in main memory. It often cannot even hold everything that one program is using. So the processor has to make decisions about what is kept in cache.

The most frequent accesses of a program are to consecutive locations in memory. Very often, after a program reads element 237 of an array, it will soon read 238, then 239, and so on. It is less often that it reads 7024 just after reading 237.

So the operation of cache is designed to keep portions of main memory that are consecutive in cache. Your `sum1` program works well with this because it changes the column index most rapidly, keeping the row index constant while all the columns are processed. The array elements it accesses are laid out consecutively in memory.

Your `sum2` program does not work well with this because it changes the row index most rapidly. This skips around in memory, so many of the accesses it makes are not satisfied by cache and have to come from slower main memory.

Related Resource: [Memory layout of multi-dimensional arrays](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/)

Comment: Further, the MMU will fetch lines of data - everything in a range of consecutive memory addresses - into the cache in one operation.  So if you're operating on data that's consecutive in memory - like a 1D array or 1D slice of a 2D array - then when array [i] is first accessed,  [i+1], [i+2]...[i+n] are automatically prefetched into cache.

Answer (score 25):

C uses *row-major ordering* to store multidimensional arrays, as documented in [**§ 6.5.2.1** *Array subscripting, paragraph 3*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p3) of the C Standard:

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object. If E is an n-dimensional array (n >= 2) with dimensions i x j x . . . x k, then E (used as other than an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an (n - 1)-dimensional array with dimensions j x . . . x k. If the unary * operator is applied to this pointer explicitly, or implicitly as a result of subscripting, the result is the referenced (n - 1)-dimensional array, which itself is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. **It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).**

Emphasis mine.

Here's an image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) that demonstrates this storage technique compared to the other method for storing multidimensional arrays, *column-major ordering*:

[image: row and column major ordering]

The first function, `sum1`, accesses data consecutively per how the 2D array is actually represented in memory, so the data from the array is already in the cache. `sum2` requires fetching of another row on each iteration, which is less likely to be in the cache.

There are some other languages that use column-major ordering for multidimensional arrays; among them are R, FORTRAN and MATLAB. If you wrote equivalent code in these languages you would observe faster output with `sum2`.

Comment: Upvoted for actually citing the standard.

Answer (score 3):

On a machine with data cache (even a 68030 has one), reading/writing data in consecutive memory locations is way faster, because a block of memory (size depends on the processor) is fetched once from memory and then recalled from the cache (read operation) or written all at once (cache flush for write operation).

By "skipping" data (reading far from the previous read), the CPU has to read the memory again.

That's why your first snippet is faster.

For more complex operations (fast fourier transform for instance), where data is read more than once (unlike your example) a lot of libraries (FFTW for instance) propose to use a *stride* to accomodate your data organization (in rows/in columns). *Never* use it, always transpose your data first and use a stride of 1, it will be faster than trying to do it without transposition.

To make sure your data is consecutive, never use 2D notation. First position your data in the selected row and set a pointer to the start of the row, then use an inner loop on that row.

```
for (i=0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    const long *row = m[i];
    for (j=0; j < COLS; j++) {
        sum += row[j];
    }
}
```

If you cannot do this, that means that your data is wrongly oriented.

Comment: Or you could just use the 2d notation in the more favorable order.

Comment: yes, but I like the concept of context: select row, work on the row. And the inner loop could be moved to another 1D-only sum/product/whatever function which uses SSE or whatever. Also, avoids a non-optimizing compiler to compute the indexes each time.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the cache.

The cache will automatically read data that lies after the data you requested. So if you read the data row by row, the next data you request will already be in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix, in memory, is align linearly, such that the items in a row are next to each other in memory (`spacial locality`).  When you transverse items in order such that you go through all of the columns in a row before moving onto the next one, when the CPU comes across an entry that isn't loaded into its cache yet, it will go and load that value along with a whole block of other values close to it in physical memory so the next several values will already be cached by the time it needs to read them.

When you transverse them the other way, the other values it loads in that are near it in memory are not going to be the next ones read, so you wind up with a lot more cache misses and so the CPU has to sit and wait while the data is brought in from the next layer of the memory hierarchy.

By the time you swing back around to another entry that you had previously cached, it more than likely has been booted out of the cache in favor of all the other data you've since loaded in as it will not have been recently used anymore (`temporal locality`)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers that this is due to cache-misses for the second program, and assuming that you are using Linux, *BSD, or MacOS, then Cachegrind may give you enlightenment. It's part of valgrind, and will run your program, without changes, and print the cache usage statistics. It does run very slowly though.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html